# Vsftpd, позволить создавать каталоги в корне?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ftp, linux-mint

```
# /etc/vsftpd.conf:

# Запускаем как демон, а не из inetd.
listen=YES
background=YES
listen_address=10.200.79.220
#listen_port=2121
#
# Включаем возможность использования tcpwrapper, лимиты через /etc/hosts.allow
tcp_wrappers=YES
#
# Пускаем только пользователей имеющих валидный shell, присутствующий в /etc/shells
check_shell=YES
#
# Вместо реальных владельцев файлов всегда показываем ftp:ftp
hide_ids=YES
#
# Общее максиамльно допустимое число коннектов.
max_clients=100
#
# Разрешенное число коннектов с одного IP.
max_per_ip=10
#
# Таймаут при ожидании команды
idle_session_timeout=3000
#
# Таймаут при передаче данных
data_connection_timeout=6000
#
# Непривилегированный пользователь, для того чтобы делать под ним, что можно выполнить без root.
nopriv_user=ftp
#
# Запрещаем рекурсивный вызов "ls -R"
ls_recurse_enable=NO
#
# Ограничение скорости прокачки для анонимных и локальных пользователей (байт в сек.)
# ====================anon_max_rate=50000
# ====================local_max_rate=100000
#
# Включаем ведение лога операций.
xferlog_enable=YES
vsftpd_log_file=/var/log/vsftpd.log
#
# Расширенные логи всех команд
log_ftp_protocol=YES
#
#
# ------------ Настрйоки для анонимного сервера

# Если сервер публичный, пускающий анонимных пользователей
anonymous_enable=YES
anon_umask=0022
# anon_umask=777
# anon_umask=055
# anon_umask=066
# anon_umask=044
# anon_umask=033
# anon_umask=022
# anon_umask=077
#
# Корень анонимного ftp архива
anon_root=/home/u0807/RecordsPolycom/
#
# Запрещаем анонимным пользователям запись данных, если нужно разрешить
# запись для локальных пользовтелей 
write_enable=YES
anon_upload_enable=YES
#
# Запрещаем создавать директории.
anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES
#
# ====error======chown_upload_mode=0777================in v.2.0.6
#
# Запрещаем переименовывать и удалять
anon_other_write_enable=YES
# Разрешаем анонимам чтение и копирование не проверенной админом информации
anon_world_readable_only=NO
# YES
#
# Если нужно запретить доступ к определенным типам файлов по маске
# deny_file={*.mp3,*.mov, *.avi, .filelist}
#
# Если нужно скрыть определенные типы файлов при выводе списка, 
# но дать скачать тем кто знает точное имя.
# hide_file={*.mp3,*.mov, *.avi}

# Если анонимную закачку необходимо разрешить, нужно дополнительно 
# использовать 
chown_uploads=YES
# chown_username=ftp_anon_user
chown_username=ftp
#
# Если нужно пускать анонимных пользователей только при правильном введении 
# email (аналог паролей для ограничения доступа к публичному ftp), заданного в 
# файле определенном директивой email_password_file, нужно установить 
# secure_email_list_enable=YES
#
#
# ------------ Настрйоки для входа локальных пользователей
#
# Если сервер разрешает вход локальных пользователей, присутствующих в системе
local_enable=YES
#
# "-rw-r--r--"
# local_umask=0022
local_umask=022
# local_umask=077
# local_umask=777
# local_umask=033
# local_umask=044
# local_umask=066
# local_umask=055
# local_umask=222
#
#
#
# Разрешаем показ файлов начинающихся с точки (например, .htaccess) для кривых ftp-клиентов
force_dot_files=YES
#
# Разрешаем пользователям записывать/изменять свою информацию на сервер.
# если нужно запретить запись данных - write_enable=NO
# Более тонкий тюнинг через "cmds_allowed=PASV,RETR,QUIT"
write_enable=YES
#
# Для всех пользователей делаем chroot, делаем корнем их домашнюю директорию,
# Список логинов для которых не нужно делать chroot задаем в vsftpd.chroot_list
chroot_local_user=YES
# chroot_list_enable=YES
# chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list
#
# Активируем список пользователей которым запрещен вход по FTP (например, root)
# userlist_enable=YES
# userlist_file=/etc/ftpusers
file_open_mode=0777
guest_enable=YES
guest_username=ftp
tilde_user_enable=YES
```

Подскажите пожалуйста что нужно поправить.
Или с авторизацией можно, главное что-бы в корне можно было каталоги создавать.

Comment: создавать по внешним запросам каталоги в `/` — это очень плохая идея. или вы под словом «корень» подразумеваете что-то иное?

Comment: _# Корень анонимного ftp архива_
    _anon_root=/home/u0807/RecordsPolycom/_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это нормальное поведение `vsftpd` начиная с версии 2.3.5
Вариантов решения несколько, например можно указать `local_root` на директорию выше:

```
 local_root=/home
```

либо (если версия vsftpd выше 3.0.0):

```
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
```

- Add new config setting `"allow_writeable_chroot"` to help people in a bit of
a spot with the v2.3.5 defensive change. Only applies to non-anonymous.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, по идее должно работать, но что-то не работает. Вот мой конфиг: [конфиг](http://paste.ubuntu.com/12881778/). Насчет _local_root_ на директорию выше, так это же просто делает корневую директорию на уровень выше. И мне нужно будет в ней сохранять. Дело в том, что есть одна железка, от Polycom, на которой сохраняются записи видеоконференций. Так вот я пытаюсь на ней настроить backup этих записей на ftp. И эта железка пытается создать папку в корне, и перенастроить эти попытки на другой каталог я не могу.

Answer (score 1):

Короче, вон оно чё: добавил,

```
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
```

создал отдельный каталог для локальных юзеров,

```
local_root=/home/u0807/Root_Local_Dir/
```

дал на него права

```
chmod 777 /home/u0807/Root_Local_Dir/
```

и заработало, всем спасибо за помощь.